# SQL: How to make a query, that checks if rows with certain value on a column, refer to a foreign key more than once?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

The database I'm working on has tables `services` and `orders`.

Each `service` has a foreign key reference as a column `fk_order`.

Now, services have a `type` column. Whenever a new `order` is created in the web-app, they'll automatically get a `service` the `type` of which is `'ORDERHANDLE'`

There was a bug at some point that MIGHT have created a situation where some `orders` would've ended up with more than one `service` with the `type` `'ORDERHANDLE'` referring to them.

What I'd like to do now is to make a query, that checks if there are multiple (more than one) `service` rows with the type `'ORDERHANDLE'` referring to one `fk_order`. Because only one `ORDERHANDLE` `type` of `service` should be referring to one `order`.

Thank you for any advice.

Here is my query so far (yes I'm a noob.)

```
SELECT * FROM services
INNER JOIN orders
ON services.fk_order = order.id
WHERE services.type = 'ORDERHANDLE'
```

I just have no idea how to proceed from there.

Comment: Can you post your query? You are looking at a simple `JOIN` with a `COUNT` and `HAVING` clauses

Comment: I did. Thanks for the comment. My query so far is just selecting the group that I'm supposed to start narrowing down by using COUNT and HAVING keywords. Thanks for pointing those out. I'm currently figuring out how to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to perform an [aggregation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aggregate_function) of the `services` table. You will need to use the `COUNT` function to count the number of `ORDERHANDLE` occurences. I'm not proficient with sql-server but something like this should work:

```
SELECT count(services.id) FROM orders
INNER JOIN services
ON services.fk_order = order.id
WHERE services.type = 'ORDERHANDLE'
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING count(services.id) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you this did it. I think I got it how to use these keywords (count, group by, having). I have to play around with them now.

Comment: I think you might want to check a nice tutorial about SQL aggregation. It will help you in the long run.

Comment: Will do. I believe so, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify rows with more than 1 foreign key reference like this:

```
SELECT orders.id, count(*) cnt
FROM services
INNER JOIN orders
ON services.fk_order = order.id
WHERE services.type = 'ORDERHANDLE'
GROUP BY orders.id
HAVING count(*) > 1
```